# Android Activate Internet

Tags: android

I create a new App with need access to the Internet.
I can check if some internet connection is on, but i try to get a new internet connection if no one is established.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni!=null && ni.isAvailable() && ni.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false; 
        }
}
```

Can some one help me.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: I want a Dialog with the question "Do you want a internet connection?" and a "yes" or "no" Button. But a find the right function for this.

Answer (score 0):

The ConnectivityManager does this for you. If there is WiFi available, the ConnectivityManager will use it, if not, it will try to use the next best (4G, 3G, etc)..

So, what you have there is the extent of checking for connectivity. If your NetworkInfo object is null, you can't access the internet.

Comment: Can you make an example for Wifi or mobile internet?